# Spring-Boot RestController: Passing Id as String not working

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongorepository

I connected my Spring-Boot-Application to a MongoDB. The application is nothing serious, just for getting into working with spring and MongoDB.

The problem it, that my id is a String and I get an Internal Server Error, when I pass the id of a database entry, in order to get it byId...

**This is my domain class:**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Document(collection = "songinfo")
public class SongInfo {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private int songId;

    private String songName;

    private String description;
}
```

**The Controller-Method:**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/songsinfo")
public class SongsInfoController {

    private final SongInfoService songInfoService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}", headers = "Accept=application/json", produces = 
        {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<SongInfo> getSongInfoById(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
        SongInfo songInfo = songInfoService.getSongInfoById(id);
        if (songInfo == null)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(songInfo, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**The SongInfoServiceImpl:***

```
@Override
public SongInfo getSongInfoById(String id) {
    return songInfoRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);
}
```

**This is the SongsInfoRepository:**

```
public interface SongInfoRepository extends MongoRepository<SongInfo, String> {

}
```

Getting all songinfos from the database is working fine:
[image: Postman_1]

But when is pass the id from one of these entries, I get this:
[image]

What is wrong here with my implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You're throwing the exception in SongInfoServiceImpl which is not handled in your SongsInfoController Class.

*Solution 1: Instead of throwing the exception return null.*

**SongInfoServiceImpl.java**

```
@Override
public SongInfo getSongInfoById(String id) {
    return songInfoRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
}
```

*Solution 2: Add try catch block*

**SongsInfoController.java**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/songsinfo")
public class SongsInfoController {

    private final SongInfoService songInfoService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}", 
        headers = "Accept=application/json", 
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}
    )
    public ResponseEntity<SongInfo> getSongInfoById(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
        SongInfo songInfo = null;
        try {
            songInfo = songInfoService.getSongInfoById(id);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(songInfo, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. That solved the error, but I don't get anything back. I did a System.out.println() in getSongInfoById() and it printed null. But if I call the EndpPoint getSongInfoBySongId instead, it's working absolutely fine. Any idea why???

Comment: Check what is getting stored in the db. If you don't mind add the sample data from db here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to divide two problem.

1. Check `id` parameter `SongsInfoController`
   Inside controller check your parameter is valid through log or sysout
2. Check `getSongInfoById` method in `SongInfoServiceImpl`
   Simply `getSongInfoById(8752);` is get error?

I want to add comment but my reputation is under 50.
If you comment above two solution check result, then I will add additional answer.